# How to make D3js object changing it's properties on mouse move near the object?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The idea is to make an object reacting on mouse moves in vicinity of the object.

That is how far I got on this by now:

```
//declaring a canvas
var canvas = d3.select("body")
               .append("svg")
               .attr("width", 100)
               .attr("height", 100);

//create circle with attributes and listeners         
var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
                    .data([1])
                    .enter()
                    .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", 50).attr("cx", 50).attr("r", 20)
  .style({"fill": "grey"})      
  .on("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

//listener on mouse move inside the canvas
function handleMouseMove(){
    var coordinates = [0, 0];
      coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
      var x = coordinates[0];
      var y = coordinates[1];
      console.log(x,y);
      console.log(this.attributes);
}
```

[See example on codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rWxMEP)

I can get the object with it's properties only when hovering over it - see last `console.log();`. And I am stuck on it. Please share your ideas regarding the solution if any.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect that the mouse is near the circle you need to set up your event handler on the object that contains the circle, in this case the `svg` contained in your `canvas` variable.  Then to determine if the mouse is close, I'd use the point [distance formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php).

```
function handleMouseMove(){
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this),
          x = coordinates[0],
          y = coordinates[1];

  var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circPos.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(circPos.y - y, 2));

  console.log("distance to circle center is " + dist);
}
```

**UPDATE FOR COMMENTS**

```js
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500)
  .on("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: Math.random() * 500,
    y: Math.random() * 500
  });
}


var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style({
    "fill": "grey"
  });

function handleMouseMove() {
  var coordinates = d3.mouse(this),
    x = coordinates[0],
    y = coordinates[1];

  circles.style("fill", "grey");

  var closestCircle = {
    obj: null,
    dist: 1e100
  };
  circles.each(function(d) {
    var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(d.x - x, 2) + Math.pow(d.y - y, 2));
    if (dist < closestCircle.dist) {
      closestCircle = {
        obj: this,
        dist: dist
      };
    }
  });

  d3.select(closestCircle.obj).style("fill", "green");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**Voroni Example**

```js
var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 500)
  .attr("height", 500);

var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  data.push({
    x: Math.random() * 500,
    y: Math.random() * 500,
    id: i
  });
}


var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("id", function(d) {
    return "circle" + d.id;
  })
  .attr("r", 10)
  .style("fill", "grey");

var voronoi = d3.voronoi()
  .extent([
    [-1, -1],
    [500 + 1, 500 + 1]
  ])
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })

var voronoiGroup = canvas.append("g")
  .attr("class", "voronoi");

voronoiGroup.selectAll("path")
  .data(voronoi.polygons(data))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    return d ? "M" + d.join("L") + "Z" : null;
  })
  .style("pointer-events", "all")
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "steelblue")
  .style("opacity", "0.5")
  .on("mouseover", mouseover);

function mouseover(d) {
  circles.style("fill", "grey");
  d3.select("#circle" + d.data.id).style("fill", "green");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mark, the problem here is that your code does not work with actual circle object (coordinates  `circPos` are not circle object properties), it simply calculates the distance which was not a question. Imagine if we work with an array of objects. How to get the one, for which mouse is, let's say, closer.

Comment: @Vadim: `it simply calculates the distance which was not a question.` - you asked how to tell if something was close to something else; seems like distance between objects, is the question.  See updated answer above.

Comment: Updated version very interesting, thank you for that.

Comment: @Vadim, another idea that comes to mind is to use a Voronoi to determine nearest circle: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7608400.

Comment: I will definitely take a look, appreciate that.

Comment: @Vadim, added an Voronoi example above.  Definitely more performant then brute force searching.  This is fun stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the cleanest way, if you can, is by putting another circle with bigger radius just under your existing circle with a fill of transparent:

```
var g = canvas.selectAll("g")
    .data([1])
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .on("mouseover", handleMouseOver) // event handlers here are applied
    .on("mouseout", handleMouseOut)   // to both 'circle'

g.append('circle').classed('invisible', true) // this goes before the
    .attr("cy", 50)                           // visible circle
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("r", 40)
    .style({"fill": "transparent"});

g.append('circle').classed('visible', true)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("r", 20)
    .style({"fill": "grey"});

    function handleMouseOver(d,i){
        d3.select(this).select('.visible').transition()
            .style({"fill": "red"});            
    };

    function handleMouseOut(d,i){
        d3.select(this).select('.visible').transition()
            .style({"fill": "green"});          
    };
```

Or if you want to use mouse positions:

```
var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
    .data([1])
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("r", 20)
        .style({"fill": "grey"})        
        .on("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

function handleMouseMove(){
    var coordinates = [];
    coordinates = d3.mouse(this);
    var x = coordinates[0];
    var y = coordinates[1];

    if (x>10 && x<90 && y>10 && y<90) {     // example values; this is a rectangle but you can use more complex shapes
         d3.select('.visible').style({"fill": "red"});
    }
    else {
        d3.select('.visible').style({"fill": "green"});
    }
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Daviz/su831xjf/) where you can see both versions.
Hope it helps...